# Merge sort bug in C

Tags: c, mergesort

I want to implement merge sort even though it is not required by the class I'm taking.

Below is my code and I have left some printf functions included to demonstrate the bug.

The program seems to work but as I get to my few final merges in the recursion it starts to go outside of the parameters of array and starts comparing garbage values.  It works because these values are positive but if one was negative it would store the value inside of my array.

I have attempted to find the bug and the best I can see it has to do with the relational operators but I cannot find the fix.

Any point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 21

int temp_array[SIZE] = {0};

void sort(int array[], int start, int end);
void merge(int array[], int start_1, int end_1, int start_2, int end_2);

int main()
{

    int array[SIZE] = {10, 1, 8, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 2, 9, 0, 100, 91, 98, 93, 96, 95, 94, 97, 92, 99};

    sort(array, 0, SIZE-1);

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        printf(" %i ", array[i]);
    }

}


void sort(int array[], int start, int end)
{
    if (end > start)
    {
        int middle = (start + end) / 2;

        // sort left half
        printf("sorting left half\n");
        sort(array, start, middle);

        // sort right half
        printf("sorting right half\n");
        sort(array, middle + 1, end);

        // merge the two halves
        printf("####MERGING#####\n");
        merge(array, start, middle, middle + 1, end);

    }
}

void merge(int array[], int start_1, int end_1, int start_2, int end_2)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int s1 = start_1;

    while(start_1<=end_1 && start_2<=end_2)
    {
        printf(" %i %i and %i %i\n", start_1, end_1, start_2, end_2);

        if(array[start_1] < array[start_2])
        {
            printf("selecting %i over %i\n", array[start_1], array[start_2]);
            temp_array[counter++] = array[start_1++];
        }

        else
        {
            temp_array[counter++] = array[start_2++];
            printf("selecting %i over %i\n", array[start_2], array[start_1]);
        }
    }

    while (start_1 <= end_1)
    {
        temp_array[counter++] = array[start_1++];
        printf("Dumping Left Half: placing %i in position %i\n", array[start_1], counter);
    }

    while (start_2 <= end_2)
    {
        temp_array[counter++] = array[start_2++];
        printf(" Dumping Right Half: placing %i in position %i\n", array[start_2], counter);
    }

    for(int i = s1, j = 0; i <= end_2; j++, i++)
    {   
        printf("Placing %i in position %i\n", temp_array[j], i);
        array[i] = temp_array[j];
    }

    return;
}
```

Comment: Slightly related, I can't stress enough how much easier an algorithm this is if you forego all those start-end pairings and just use a base address, some pointer arithmetic, and a *length*  when descending into your recursion calls. C is a *beautiful* thing on that regard. Dance with the one you brought. That said, a debugger would be your next turn. I didn't downvote this only because inline-message-debugging has obviously been tried, which is honestly more effort than most people put in before coming here. Props for that, at least.

Comment: The code seems to work fine on my machine--can you show us an example of this bug you get?

Comment: It's not necessary to say in your title that the source code is included. We have eyes.

Comment: Note: simple example of what I referred to in my first comment [can be seen **here**](http://ideone.com/81czTG). if I get a chance I'll take a peek at your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, can definitely see how your example flows and is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that looks suspicious to me is this inside that `else` in your merge code:

```
temp_array[counter++] = array[start_2++];
printf("selecting %i over %i\n", array[start_2 /* HERE */], array[start_1]);
```

Assuming `start_2 == end_2` holds before the above is executed, then the `printf` will read from index `end_2 + 1`, which will be out of bounds in the outermost recursive call of `sort` and thus undefined behaviour (that might result in printing garbage).

Comment: You beat me, the algorithm works, the debug message is producing an out of bound access.

Comment: Thanks you, figures the code is right and the printf's are put after the execution.  Motivation to start using the debugger more.